# I need to download the csv file from URL in unix korn shell using curl command

Tags: shell, unix, curl

There is one URL which will download the csv file, I have to use it in Unix shell script using 'curl' command. Because the already existing script was using the same script, Since the URL has been changed now but its not working with the new URL. This URL should download the csv file & store in the xyz.csv filename.
Command already used in existing script, which is connecting to Proxy server using ssh & then removing the already existing file & store the content from the url in the same file :

```
ssh ${PROXY_SERVER} "rm -f ${SHARED_DATE_FILE} && /usr/bin/curl --silent  https://example.com/files/${URL_DATE}.txt > $SHARED_DATE_FILE"
```

I am trying the below command

```
ssh ${PROXY_SERVER} "rm -f ${SHARED_DATE_FILE} && /usr/bin/curl --silent  https://example-123.com/dts/inrs?format=csv > $SHARED_DATE_FILE"
```

I can't mention the actual URL here but the URL I have is actually downloading the file in csv format. but its not working through script. it says curl not found. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If `curl` is not installed on the remote server the rest of the script is pointless. Install `curl` if it is missing; correct the path if it is wrong in your script.

Comment: Since you provided the absolute path to `curl`, it simply means that on the remote host there is no `curl` in this directory. You can ask the admin of the remote host if he has installed it, and if so, in which directory.

Comment: curl is installed on the server I checked. The problem is that in the old url the the url itself has the filename with txt format with URL_DATE(20231129) on it. So its easily get downloaded & stored in the new file.
```
'ssh ${PROXY_SERVER} "rm -f ${SHARED_DATE_FILE} && /usr/bin/curl --silent  https://example.com/files/${URL_DATE}.txt > $SHARED_DATE_FILE"'
```
Whereas in the new URL the link is downloading in csv format with ? on it in the url. but this is not storing in the new through script. Manually I am doing it in putty its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the <kbd>?</kbd> character, which is special for filename expansions. Try quoting the url:

```bash
ssh ${PROXY_SERVER} "\
  rm -f ${SHARED_DATE_FILE} && \
  /usr/bin/curl --silent 'https://example-123.com/dts/inrs?format=csv' > $SHARED_DATE_FILE"
```